# Java interceptor not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I have a Spring boot application and I am implementing and interceptor in order to log some data.
The problem is that is not getting called, I have tried:

```
@Interceptor
public class LoggerInterceptor{

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object collectBasicLoggingInformation(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(context.getClass());
        logger.info("Method Called: " + context.getMethod()
                .getName());
        logger.info("Parameters: " + Arrays.toString(context.getParameters()));
        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

And then I've applied to methods or classes and in both of them doesn't work:

```
@GetMapping
@Interceptors(LoggerInterceptor.class)
public List getAllFilingNumber(){
    logger.info("This is a test");
    return filingNumberService.findAll();
}
```

Or

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(FilingNumberController.BASE_URL)
@Interceptors(LoggerInterceptor.class)
public class FilingNumberController{

    @GetMapping
    public List getAllFilingNumber(){
        logger.info("This is a test");
        return filingNumberService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Does someone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **having a springboot application** in order to intercept the request to a controller , you have to take a **different approach** altogethor.

> **Interceptors are used in conjunction with Java EE managed classes** to
>   allow developers to invoke interceptor methods on an associated target
>   class, in conjunction with method invocations or lifecycle events.
>   Common uses of interceptors are logging, auditing, and profiling.
>   Reference [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html)

You are trying to use Java EE annotation with spring , which won't work.In spring-boot you will have to **register the interceptors like** :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(new ThemeChangeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/admin/**");
        registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/secure/*");
    }
}
```

The interceptor itself have to be a class which extends the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`  and implements the methods as follows.
From Spring [DOCS](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) :

> All HandlerMapping implementations support handler interceptors that
>   are useful when you want to apply specific functionality to certain
>   requests — for example, checking for a principal. Interceptors must
>   implement HandlerInterceptor from the org.springframework.web.servlet
>   package with three methods that should provide enough flexibility to
>   do all kinds of pre-processing and post-processing:
>
> ```
> preHandle(..): Before the actual handler is executed
>
> postHandle(..): After the handler is executed
>
> afterCompletion(..): After the complete request has finished
> ```

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("we are Intercepting the Request");
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object object, ModelAndView model)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("request processing "
            + "completed by @RestController");

 }

 @Override
 public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object object, Exception arg3)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("afterCompletion Request Completed");
 }
}
```